# How to store metadata describing documents in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, metadata, database

What is the best way to store metadata that describe a collection in MongoDB?

I have a collection with an arbitrary and changing number of documents within.  As I create new documents, I want to assign a new, temporary name (String) based on the number of documents currently in the collection, e.g. "Doc 1", "Doc 2", ...  Since documents could be removed, just doing a count() will not yield a useful result.

One option is to store metadata describing a collection within a different collection, but this seems awkward.

Since Mongo is schema-free, I could keep the collection's metadata within the collection itself, perhaps within a document with the name "metadata".  In that case, how would I access that document quickly?  Would I need to build an index for "metadata" to get at it immediately, without O(n) search time?

Is there a more standard, or simpler, way than what I described in the previous paragraph?  I may end up with more metadata in the future than just a count.

Comment: Why can't you just use the unique _id that gets added to each of the documents. This is as good as a sequential counter.i.e. a surrogate key.

Comment: I definitely agree with you, upvoted. I would love to have metadata built-in in the collection itself. We could have something similar to "db.collection.Product.setMetadata({ data1: dataValue })" and similarly to get the metadata as "db.collection.Product.getMetadata()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/.

According to the link above, my opinion is that just storing those in a colleciton named `metadata` with the format:

```
{
    '_id':'collection1'
    'c': 0,
    'other metadata1': 'foo',
    'other metadata2': 'bar'
}
```

Then you can get those metadata according to the collection name.
If you want to add a field to this document, just use [$set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$set) with update.

Comment: yeah, that link implies that creating a collection dedicated to metadata is recommended.  seems weird...i'll wait to hear any other ideas before accepting.  thanks

Comment: You can as well use the collection where you are storing the documents themselves to have the metadata/counter doc

Comment: @Pangea, that was what i described in my question, but if i do that, do i need to make an index on some field unique to that metadata document in order to find the doc in constant time, instead of linear?

Comment: You have to add an index on the field if you want to store metadata in the same collection. But for better maintanance, I would use a collection to store it :)

Answer (score 4):

What we often do is put settings or metadata or so in a separate, one-document collection .settings.
eg. if your data is located in collection 'user', I put the metadata in 'user.settings'